# Writing a script for converting blue source folders to yellow in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I was writing an Xcode file template and attempted to group the created file but it turns out that it is not possible with file template and is only possible with project template. However I created folders statically inside xctemplate and now they are blue instead of groups which are yellow and recommended to house swift files. My question is that is it possible to write a script that will turn those blue folders into yellow groups? Because I created an MVP-C template as my company is using MVP-C and my TL asked me to always create a folder for each scene and inside each scene a separate folder for Model, View, Presenter, Coordinator. Please see the reference image for better understanding of problem.

[image]

Comment: just try to add group.

Comment: That’ll be doing manually, I am trying to automate the stuff here.

Comment: i think terminal will help out here. search command it might be helpful

Comment: That is why I posted this question because I was not aware of the command, do you happen to know any? If so please share. It will save a lot of time.